# @OnetoMany class call

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

i need some help for my class...

```
package com.it.ese.orbit.entity;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;



/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Shahriar Newaz
 * Date: 07/03/11
 * Time: 10.07
 */
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy =InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class OrbitObject {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue


    @Column(name="id",nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="Scenario",nullable = false)
    private String scenario;  // not sure about how to map scenario

    @Column(name="code",nullable = true)
    private String code;

    @Column(name="name",nullable = true)
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Bia bia;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Impatti impatti;


    @Column(name="parent",nullable = true)
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private OrbitObject OrbitObject;


    public Long getId() {
     return id;
    }

    protected void setId(Long id) {
     this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
     return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
     this.code = code;
    }



    public String getScenario() {
        return scenario;
    }
    public void setScenario(String scenario) {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        name = name;
    }

     // LOG
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "com.it.ese.orbit.models.OrbitObject["
        + " - name="+name + " - scenario="+scenario +" - id= "+id+"]";
    }
}
```

But i get thi error...

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.it.ese.orbit.entity.OrbitObject.OrbitObject

I wish i create an OrbitObject field as like an object of the same class...
Help please!

Answer (score 5):

You either do

```
@Column(name="parent",nullable = true)
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private OrbitObject OrbitObject;
```

Or

```
@Column(name="parent",nullable = true)
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<OrbitObject> OrbitObject;
```

The first case implies this entity will be the owning side, namely, it will have the foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

OneToMany means that OrbitObject has many OrbitObject children, which is not true because the OrbitObject property is not a collection.
You must convert it to a ManyToOne

Answer (score 0):

you can use @OneToMany referring to a collection of elements, for example

```
@OneToMany
List<OrbitObject> orbitList;
```